# Describe the splitting field $F$ of the polynomial $f=x^4+x^2+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $x^4 +  x^2 + 1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ so the roots of $f$ are $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$.  I am just having trouble writing this in terms of $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,..)$.  Would it just be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ since $\frac{1}{2} \in mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. You already know the roots in $\mathbb{C}$, which are expressible as elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, so all that really remains to show is that no smaller field extension will split the polynomial. This follows because the roots are not in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$, so there are no intermediate fields.

Comment: Thank you! How does $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}): \mathbb{Q}] = 2$ tell us that there are no intermediate fields?

Comment: Because $1$ and $2$ has "no intermediate" integer degree.